# Neo4j: How to display communities after applying Label Propagation Algorithm (LPA)

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I have 565 articles in Neo4j and I ran LPA to obtain clusters.

I have the following result: 69 communities.

I would like to display all the communities at the same time in Neo4j.

I tried several Cypher queries with the property key 'community' but it didn't work.

My data looks like this:

[image]

How can I do it ?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: I tried this : 

`MATCH (n) WHERE EXISTS(n.community) RETURN n, n.community` 

It displays all the article nodes but not the communities.

When I do this : `MATCH (n) WHERE n.community = 1102 RETURN n, n.title`

I can see one community.

Comment: I think this is a simple issue. You are probably using the neo4j Browser's `Graph` [view](https://neo4j.com/docs/browser-manual/current/operations/result-frames/), which only shows returned nodes and relationships. Try using the `Text` or `Table` view to see all the returned values. Your first query should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you are using the neo4j Browser to visualize your results.

When your Cypher query returns any *nodes, relationships, or paths*, the browser will automatically show you the `Graph` view (on the left side of the result panel, you should see icons with captions that may include `Graph`, `Table`, `Text`, etc.). The `Graph` view only shows nodes and relationships, and not anything else that was returned.

However, if you click on the other icons (say, `Table` or `Text`), you should see more results -- like the communities, presented in different formats.

*By the way, specifying the node label would make your query more efficient (and adding an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) would make it even more efficient if you have a lot of ARTICLE nodes):*

```
MATCH (n:ARTICLE) WHERE EXISTS(n.community)
RETURN n, n.community
```

Comment: How can I control the number of communities in LPA? I know that there is no explicit parameter for this. But can I use another algorithm after LPA to have a limited no. of communities, like k-means?

Comment: That should be posed as a new question, and you should provide complete details about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74224750/3361967

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74585342/3361967

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74252171/3361967

Comment: https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science/issues/229