# Louvain Community Detection Algorithm, How to identify the no. of clusters?

Tags: neo4j, cluster-analysis

I want to use **Louvain** for clustering a large-scale network. How can I identify the number of the **required clusters** since there is no parameter that can be configured for this purpose in the algorithm built in Neo4j (Graph Data Science) library?

**Update 1**: according to this [Ref],[1](https://medium.com/neo4j/k-means-clustering-with-neo4j-b0ec54bf0103) k-means can be used to group items based on similar properties instead of relationships (nodes without the relationships between them). since I have a complete network topology, I think that K-means doesn't work in this scenario.

**Update 2:** Any suggestion about another algorithm (s) that can perform clustering and allows specifying the no. of clusters is welcomed :)

The aim of clustering is to create multiple network domains to distribute the traffic load in a large-scale SDN network, so I thought to use a community detection algorithm to perform the clustering so that to determine the required no. of SDN controllers to be deployed.

Answer (score 2):

Louvain optimizes modularity by combining smaller communities into larger groups until some end state is reached. So the end number of clusters isn't under user control.

K-Means (available in alpha) allows you to pre-set the number of clusters, if that helps.

You might also edit your question to explain why Louvain is the method you'd like to go with, so people can offer suggestions that support your use case. :)

Comment: This got a little too domain-specific for me to be help out any more, but it's a good update and I hope you get a useful answer. =)