# Network graph clustering

Tags: neo4j, cluster-analysis, k-means, sdn

I have a large-scale network consisting of 62,578 nodes. It represents the network topology of an SDN network (Software Defined Networking).

- I want to partition the graph into a number of clusters, each cluster should be controlled by an SDN controller.
- I tried to use the **k-means** algorithm, but it doesn't take into account the relationships between the nodes. This algorithm relies on the nodes and their properties.
- Then I tried the **similarity algorithm**, but it calculates the similarity score between 2 nodes and creates a new relationship that holds this value between these 2 nodes. As a result, I couldn't benefit from this way in **k-means** algorithm.
- **Louvain** and **Leiden** don't allow the number of clusters in advance. Is there any way to do that with these algorithms?

Suggestions Please. Any idea may be of great help to me. Many thanks.

Update: This photo is part of the whole graph.

[image]

Update 2:

```
CALL gds.graph.project  
(
    'myGraph',
    'node',
    'to',
    {
        relationshipProperties: 'cost'
    }
)

CALL gds.fastRP.write
(
  'myGraph',
  {
    embeddingDimension: 1,
    writeProperty: 'fastrp-embedding'
  }
)
YIELD nodePropertiesWritten  

 CALL gds.graph.project
    (
        'myGraph_1',
        {
          node: {
            properties: 'fastrp-embedding'
          }
        },
        '*'
    )

CALL gds.alpha.kmeans.write 
('myGraph_1', 
{
  nodeProperty: 'fastrp-embedding',
  k: 3,
  randomSeed: 42,
  writeProperty: 'kmeans'
})
YIELD nodePropertiesWritten
```

**Update 3:**

I applied FastRP to create node embeddings for a graph consisting of 6,301 nodes. These embeddings are stored as node properties to be used in clustering using the K-means algorithm. I noticed that although the nodes are nearby to each other, they are assigned to different clusters.

**Notes:**

- For FastRP, I set the embedding dimensions to 256.
- For K-means, I set K to 2.
- I tried a smaller embedding equals 2, 4, etc, The same results occurred.
- In addition, I tried another graph size with 8,846 nodes. Similar incomprehensible results occurred.
- I didn't specify a random seed for FastRP. I didn't know how to set a preferred value for this parameter. I it related to the graph size like the node embedding?

For the sub-graph below, the following are the results of clustering:

[image]
[image]

Comment: @MichaelHunger Wish you have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define the number of clusters, you can try the following.

First create node embeddings using any of the available models like the FastRP or node2vec. Next, use the k-means algorithm to cluster nodes based on the embeddings.

Use the mutate mode for the FastRP and store the results under lets say `embedding` property. Next, run k-means algorithm on the embeddings like in the example:

```
CALL gds.alpha.kmeans.write('cities', {
  nodeProperty: 'embedding',
  k: 3,
  writeProperty:'cluster'
})
```

where the `k` parameter defines the number of clusters and the `nodeProperty` should point to the `embedding` property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I run the FastRP and got the embedding (4-dimensional vector since I set the embedding Dimension to 4)  for each node. How can I use it in K-means? Please can you clarify more?

Comment: edited the asn wers

Comment: Well, it works :). But I didn't understand how the embedding values are computed. Is it affected by the relationships between the nodes? BTW, I set the embedding Dimension to 1.

Comment: set embedding dimension to 128 probably.

Comment: Can I send you the CSV file of the graph? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated the question with the steps that I used to get the clusters as you said.

Comment: You can change the k value to the number of clusters you want

Comment: Are the resulting embeddings from the FastRP exhibiting the node and its relationships with its neighbors? Since it's an essential factor in clustering the graph using the K-means algorithm.

Comment: Take a look at: https://medium.com/towards-data-science/behind-the-scenes-on-the-fast-random-projection-algorithm-for-generating-graph-embeddings-efb1db0895

Comment: Please @tomaz can you give me an advice for this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74295387/neo4j-gds-algorithms-execution-time]

Comment: Please @tomaz can you give me an advice?