# Neo4j GDS algorithms execution time

Tags: neo4j, execution-time

I run the **Dijkstra source-target shortest path** algorithm in Neo4j (community edition) for 7 different graphs. The sizes of these graphs are as follows: 6,301 nodes - 8,846 nodes - 10,876 nodes - 22,687 nodes - 26,518 nodes - 36,682 nodes - 62,586 nodes.

For all these graphs, the results (the path) are received in **2 ms** and completed at different amounts of times. Is it OK that the time is the same for all these graphs regardless of their sizes?
The same is happening when running the **Yen** algorithm.

If the time provided by the Neo4j browser is inaccurate, how can I measure the execution time accurately?

Update (tracking the execution time):

[image: Time]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @tomaz Bwratanic

Comment: How do you track the execution time?

Comment: I updated the question about how to track the execution time. Is it beneficial to use the enterprise edition to get the query log which contains timing info?