# Label Propagation + K means in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, k-means

Can I use the k means after Label Propagation? I stored the community as a node property. However, an error occurred:
Failed to invoke procedure gds.alpha.kmeans.write: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

I think that the community should be converted to float and stored as an array. How can I store it as an array?
Update:
I use this script:

//Label_Propagation

```
CALL gds.labelPropagation.write
('myGraph_1',
 {   maxIterations:15,
     writeProperty: 'community' 
 }
)
YIELD communityCount, ranIterations, didConverge
```

//Community Set to array of float

```
MATCH (n:node) SET n.community = [Tofloat(n.community)]
```

//K-means Write

```
CALL gds.alpha.kmeans.write('myGraph_1', {
  nodeProperty: 'community',
  k: 2,
  writeProperty: 'kmeans'
})
YIELD communityDistribution
```

Now the community property is stored as a list of floats (1 value). However, when running the k-means, the same error occurs.

Comment: What would this achieve?

Comment: To reduce the communities, as I think. For a graph consisting of 62,586 nodes, the no. of communities resulting from running the LPA (Label Propagation Algorithm) is 203. I don't have any control over the no. of communities in LPA so I'm using K means to reduce it to a specified number (k).